# Search Engine - Bold text in results then come back to normal when nothing is in input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the text in the results bold but I can't manage to do so
Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search here...">
<div class = "sometext">
Sentence going here
</div>
<div class = "sometext">
Sentence going there
</div>
<div class = "sometext">
Sentence going somewhere
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
  function search() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('sometext');
    var regex = new RegExp(input, 'gi');
    sometextvalues = [];
    for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
    sometextvalues[j] = x[j].innerHTML;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            str = sometextvalues[i];
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
                if (input){
                x[i].style.display="flex";
              var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>' + input + '</b>');
                x[i].innerHTML = result;
            }
            else{
            x[i].innerHTML = sometextvalues[i];
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

So the problem is that right now, the bold text only appears for one letter and then the results don't appear anymore. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are highlighting the innerText of elements with class `sometext` if the text in the serach input field at the first keyUp event is matching by adding `<b></b>` tag and then matching the modified inner text against new search string on your next `keyup` event. Lets say you enter 's' in serach field and then the texts in `sometext` would be changed to

```
<b>S</b>entence going here
<b>S</b>entence going there
<b>S</b>entence going somewhere
```

then you are typing 'e' next to 's' in the serach field, then you are trying to match the text '`<b>S</b>entence going here`' against '`se`' which will return false always so there onwards the highlighting won't work.

to fix the issue, always remove `<b>` and `</b>` tags from the innterTexts of elements with class `sometext` before matching it with the input text.

```js
function search() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('sometext');
    var regex = new RegExp(input, 'gi');
    sometextvalues = [];
    for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
        sometextvalues[j] = x[j].innerHTML.replaceAll('<b>','').replaceAll('</b>','');
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        str = sometextvalues[i].replaceAll('<b>','').replaceAll('</b>','');
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.replaceAll('<b>','').replaceAll('</b>','').toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            if (input){
                x[i].style.display="flex";
                var result = str.replace(regex, '<b>' + input + '</b>');
                x[i].innerHTML = result;
            }
            else {
                x[i].innerHTML = sometextvalues[i];
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search here...">
<div class = "sometext">
Sentence going here
</div>
<div class = "sometext">
Sentence going there
</div>
<div class = "sometext">
Sentence going somewhere
</div>
```

I have only corrected the highlighting part since that is the main focus of your question. You can put some effort yourself to correct some other issues like the formatted lower cased text is being set with `sometext` elements, dropping space between words when a whole word is searched, etc...

Comment: Thank you! As in for the other details, those are for later, I was just wondering why this wasn't really working